# How can i select values from 2d array and add to another 2d array python

Tags: python, arrays

So i want to take each value from a list in a 2d array into its own separate 2d array for use later. 
I have this code:

```
for i in portalsAll:
    for x in i:
        tpinx.append(x.split(" ")[0])
        tpiny.append(x.split(" ")[1])
        tpoutx.append(x.split(" ")[2])
        tpouty.append(x.split(" ")[3])
    tpIn_x.append(tpinx)
    tpIn_y.append(tpiny)
    tpOut_x.append(tpoutx)
    tpOut_y.append(tpouty)
```

and this is the 2d array i wish to take the values from:

```
[['0 0 1 2', '0 2 2 0', '2 2 1 0'], ['1 0 2 0', '8 0 3 0', '0 0 9 0']]
```

As you can see, there are spaces between the values, which i cannot delete as i took this data from a file, and is why i split it to remove the spaces.
However this code does not work and it replies for `tpIn_x` ,as an example,

```
 [['0', '0', '2', '1', '8', '0'], ['0', '0', '2', '1', '8', '0']]
```

which is a 2d array consisting of 2 repeated lists. 
My ideal output is

`[['0', '0', '2'], ['1', '8', '0']]`

where it would only put the data in each list from the corresponding list in the original 2d array, by the way the list sizes in the 2d array is not set to 3 so i cannot set a maximum list size.

How can i fix this? Any help is gratefully accepted.

Comment: can you be explicite about the expected output : what for tpIn_x, tpIn_y, tpOut_x, tpOut_y ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in portalsAll:
    tpIn_x.append([x.split()[0] for x in i])
    tpIn_y.append([x.split()[1] for x in i])
    tpOut_x.append([x.split()[2] for x in i])
    tpOut_y.append([x.split()[3] for x in i])
```